# RailsTutorial Chapter 8 Tests Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, railstutorial.org

I am working through chapter 8 of Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial ([www.railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org)) and have encountered failing tests (both failures and errors). I've spent several hours trying to get these tests to pass, and have read similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of the answers have fixed my problem.

Here are the messages for the failing tests:

```
1) Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25]:
expecting <"users/show"> but rendering with <["statics/home", "layouts/_shim", "layouts/_header", "layouts/_footer", "layouts/application"]>

2) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
test/integration/user_login_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

3) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
test/integration/user_login_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

And related files:

**users_signup_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "foo",
                               password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                                        email: "user@stpauls.school.nz",
                                        password:              "password",
                                        password_confirmation: "password" }
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

**user_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:someName)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: "" } }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                      password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    flash.now[:success] = 'Successfully logged out!'
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical     order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password]     || 'example'
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

**users.yml**

```
somename:
  name: "SomeName"
  email: "somename@someemail.com"
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

As I've said, I've spent a long time trying to fix these errors with no luck. Any help is appreciated! It's also worth mentioning that I've been changing the names/values of some variables throughout, but I believe I've been consistent in the renaming so this shouldn't be affecting anything.

Sorry for the superlong post.

Comment: params[:session] is empty for the last two...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the errors log suggested that this syntax:

**Rails 5**

```
`post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email, 
                                                      password: 'password' } }`
```

is Rails 5 syntax. `post` and other http request methods has changed in rails 5. To fix this issue either upgrade to rails 5 simply use rails 4 syntax:

**Rails 4**

```
post login_path, session: { email:    @user.email,
                                      password: 'password' } }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. This fixes the error (Looks like you used one too many `}` though), but the test is failing anyway - the error message is identical to the first message in my original question.

Comment: you really can not try to work through the railstutorial that was updated to version 5 of rails with a rails 4. I suggest starting over with either the right rails version or the right version of the tutorial (old one should still be available somewhere).